# File inside subprocess.call() does not work, but original script works fine

Tags: python, postgresql, subprocess

I am trying to make PostgreSQL function that executes Python script file `test.py`. The main goal of `test.py` is to create new table in PostgreSQL database named `test_2`.

test.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd


db_config = {'user': '******', 
    'pwd': '*******',
    'host': '*******',
    'port': ****,
    'db': '*******'} 

connection_string = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(db_config['user'],
    db_config['pwd'],
    db_config['host'],
    db_config['port'],
    db_config['db'])

engine = create_engine(connection_string) 

test_df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1], columns= ['A', 'B'], data = 0)


test_df\
.to_sql(
    'test_2',
    schema='database',
    con=engine,
    if_exists='replace',
    index=False
)
```

PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION optimacros.test()
RETURNS VOID
AS $$
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:/ProgramData/anaconda3/python.exe', 'C:/Users/User1/Desktop/test.py'])
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u
```

When  I execute that it gives me `Query complete`, but there is no new table `test_2` in database.

I tried to run this part in Jupyter Notebook:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:/ProgramData/anaconda3/python.exe', 'C:/Users/User1/Desktop/test.py'])
```

It returns me '2' (my `test_2` has 2 rows), but still no `test_2` in database.

However, if I run original code from `test.py` in Jupyter Notebook (without using `subprocess.call()` it works well and `test_2` appears in my database.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 2 questions: 1) Could you post the contents of test.py? And when you say running the code works, do you mean you're running test.py with a python interpreter or are you copying the CREATE TABLE query out and executing that by some other means? 2) If the main goal of test.py is to create a table, do you really need a database function which calls a python function to create that table, or could your initial database function not just create the table? Maybe the python script is used to reference some external data/condition?

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: "It returns me '2'" it may be the return code of Python indicating that the file was not found.

Comment: @MattSmith 1) Posted contents of `test.py`. The code works only when I copy contents of `test.py` and run it in Jupyter Notebook. 2) You are right, purpose of `test.py` is to test work of Postgre function (is it possible to create table in PostgreSQL using Python), further goal will be more complicated, but it still will create table in database. So, for now I am trying just to create random table in PostgreSQL using Python and Postgre functions

Comment: @Krutyi4el I edited a post al little (added contents of `test.py`). Python returns 2, because table, which added to database has 2 rows (`.to_sql()` returns number of rows exported). So the code works, but still no table in database

Comment: @furas Thanks! I am really new to Postgre functions, so have some troubles... But I will try "print debuging"

Comment: Before I saw the contents of test.py I suspected that there might somehow be a problem with not committing after table creation but it looks like the DataFrame.to_sql method should auto commit according to its docs, so it's probably not that. How exactly are you verifying whether or not table test_2 has been created in the database? Not to be that guy, but is it possible you're checking the result in a different database? Or for example if you're using pgAdmin and glancing at the object tree, the table won't be listed there unless the tree list is refreshed.

Comment: @MattSmith, You are right about me using pgAdmin, but the database I am checking is the right one (the same where table being created when I am running code from `test.py` in Jupyter Notebook). And I am refreshing object tree to see the table in it. Don't know what is happening here actually...

Comment: (For the record, the database is named Postgres, though the full name is PostgreSQL, where they "reuse" the S to be cute. See also https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/10/postgres-vs-postgresql.html)

Comment: If the host is `localhost` and you are somehow connecting to one of the environments remotely, you have two different databases.